# Check how much text can fit in 3 lines of TextView

Tags: android, textview, line

In my app I am getting comments from Instagram. I want to make a small window for reading not more, than first 3 lines of comment text. Also I want to add "Show all" at the end of the third line. I don't need to reformat the text, I just want to cut off the "tail" after first 3 lines and to add "Show all" in place of last 8 symbols.

The only way to solve it right now I see in creating additional textview, where I'll set maxLines, then obtain the text displayed in it, add "Show all" instead of last 8 symbols and paste it into the necessary TextView.

I hope there is a better solution.

Comment: did you try android:ellipsize property on the textview?

Comment: Will the text be overwritten? I need to shrink the text and then to add "Show all" at the end.

Comment: When using ellipsize, android cuts the text to fit into the textview and adds "..." at the end. You could write a custom View component (extends TextView) and change ellipsize's behavior to add a "Show all"-Button/Link/whatever instead of "...". This is, of course, an advanced task, but the cleanest solution.

Comment: Maybe there is anything easier? I'm lost in the source code of TextView class

Comment: I'm afraid Android does not provide an out-of-the-box solution for this. Just read the tutorials regarding UI component development on developer.android.com, it's a good entry point. Although you'll need some ramp-up time for developing UI components, I think thats worth the time since you will need custom UI components in many cases, especially if you want to develop 'fancy' UIs.